# How to Change the Column of a Database in codeigniter for 2 hours. After 2 hours its reset to its default value in php codeigniter

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

Like if I have a `driver` table there is column `driver_status`, if some book this `driver` for 2 hours then I want to change its status `driver_status =2`, by which nobody can book this `driver` at this time, After 2 hours I want to reset its `driver_status =1` its means now the `driver` is available for booking.

Comment: Welcome to the SO. Please read this first [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Many many wants to accomplish this. How would you like to accomplish it?

One method of execution would be to set a timestamp on the driver, or in another table, when driver_status is set to 2. Then just use a cron job every hour, get all drivers whose status = 2 and check their respective timestamp. Update the status to = 1 when some logic is valid.